# what is the diffrence between (in the body) are in django 3.1

Tags: python, html, django

is it just me or other people don't understand the title
because docs.djangoproject.com wasn't clear enough, so I'm just asking what the differences between `<li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>`

```
<li><a href="{% url 'detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
```

Comment: The thing is... It is same if you don't have to change `/polls/` but, what if you want to do `/poll/`. You have to change ``<li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li> `` this line individually . But, when you do with what django says, you can just edit `/polls/' to `/poll/` in `urls.py`

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of the same thing, in the first example you are just giving it the name of the direct URL, while, in the second example, you are specifying the URL name with polls!

That's it. Nothing too crazy!